# Sort list itmes according to child element value

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, date, logic

There are are more than one `li` tags. Inside those `li` tags there is a `span` element which has a value of a month. What I want is to sort thes `li` tags using the **month** text value of the `span` element inside the `li` tag.

For example; If there is `li` tag and inside the `li` tag there is a `span` with `December` as its `innerHTML`, This `li` tag should be at the bottom of the list since `December` is the last month of the year.

Below is the html code.

```html
<ul class="timeline-items">
                <h2 class="fables-second-background-color date-circle">2018</h2>
                <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
                    <span class="gallery-mlti-date">MAY</span>
                </li>
                <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
                    <span class="gallery-mlti-date">NOV</span>
                </li>
                <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
                    <span class="gallery-mlti-date">SEP</span>
                </li>
                <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
                    <span class="gallery-mlti-date">NOV</span>
                </li>
            </ul>

      <script>
      const months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
     </script>
```

I've tried many approaches to achieve this using javascript but my I'm out of logix. Feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with actual dates and the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor. This way you can evaluate exact dates with each other and use them in a sorting function. You already have the month, but in this case the year is also necessary to build a valid date. The minimal requirement is a year. In this case we need both the year and the month.

I've used the HTML5 [`<time>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) element which makes your date more semantic. It has a `datetime` attribute which screen readers and search engines can read to know what date, for example, `NOV` is. We can use the value in the `datetime` attribute to create a new date with the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor.

First select all the [`<time>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) elements and use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or the spread syntax `[...elements]` to create an array from the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) result. This is needed to use the `sort` method which is available in all arrays.

In the [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method compare the values from the `datetime` attribute with each other to create the order. Now the order has been set we want to apply it to the document. Loop through the dates again and use the `order` property of Flexbox to set the correct order based on the index of the sorted array.

You'll also need to add `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column` on your `<ul>` element to make the `<li>` elements work with the `order` property.

Let me know if I haven't been clear or if you have some more questions.

```js
// Get the <time> elements and put them in an array.
const dates = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-mlti-date'));

// Sort by date. From January to December.
dates.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.dateTime) - new Date(b.dateTime));

// Set order of list items by index of sorted list.
dates.forEach((date, index) => date.parentElement.style.order = index);
```

```css
.timeline-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="fables-second-background-color date-circle">2018</h2>
<ul class="timeline-items">
  <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
    <time datetime="2020-05" class="gallery-mlti-date">MAY</time>
  </li>
  <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
    <time datetime="2020-11" class="gallery-mlti-date">NOV</time>
  </li>
  <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
    <time datetime="2020-09" class="gallery-mlti-date">SEP</time>
  </li>
  <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
    <time datetime="2020-11" class="gallery-mlti-date">NOV</time>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Using the built–in parser on unsupported timestamp formats is not a good idea. The dates will sort lexically using the * datetime* attribute, there's no need for Date objects.

Comment: You sir, are correct. Using the dates a simply strings will also do the trick. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Please don't call me "sir", in my culture, it's not a compliment. :-)

Comment: My apologies. I meant no disrespect, Rob. What culture is yours, if I may ask?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```html
<h2 class="fables-second-background-color date-circle">2018</h2>
  
  <ul class="js-timeline-list timeline-items">
      <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
          <span class="gallery-mlti-date">MAY</span>
      </li>
      <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
          <span class="gallery-mlti-date">NOV</span>
      </li>
      <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
          <span class="gallery-mlti-date">SEP</span>
      </li>
      <li class="is-hidden timeline-item">
          <span class="gallery-mlti-date">NOV</span>
      </li>
  </ul>

  <script>
    function sortList(list) {
        let i = 0;
        const months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
        const children = list.children;
      
        for (i = 1; i < children.length; i++) {
            for (let j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                let leftChild = children[j].children[0].innerHTML;
                let rightChild = children[j - 1].children[0].innerHTML;

                if (months.indexOf(leftChild) >= months.indexOf(rightChild)) continue;
                children[j].parentNode.insertBefore(children[j], children[j - 1]);
            }
        }
        
    }
  
    const root = document.querySelector('.js-timeline-list');
    sortList(root)
  </script>
```